# Context in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function katana(){
  this.isSharp = true;
}
katana();
assert( isSharp === true, "A global object now exists with that name and value." );

var shuriken = {
  toss: function(){
    this.isSharp = true;
  }
};
shuriken.toss();
assert( shuriken.isSharp === true, "When it's an object property, the value is set within the object." );
```

I am actually not getting what is this code trying to tell?. Can anyone explain me what is Context in JavaScript and what exactly does context represent here in the above code?

Comment: it's just about private and global variables

Comment: It means katanas are not sharp, but windows are. (pardon for the joke, it's the holidays you know?)

Comment: [Read this when you'll be ready](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: This should help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the reason `this === window` in the first example and `this === shuriken` in the second example all has to do with where those functions are created. Notice that when you define `shuirken.toss` outside of the object, `this` points to the window object. And when you call `katana` with `new`, `this` points to the newly created object.

Answer (score 3):

The first call is equivalent to:

```
katana.call(window); // window is now referenced as this inside the function
```

In a similar fashion, you could change the call to `katana()` like this to change the context:

```
var shuriken = {}
katana.call(shuriken); // shuriken.isSharp === true
```

The second invocation implicitly has this equivalent function call:

```
shuriken.toss.call(shuriken);
```